# Is there a way to calculate the total length of all paths in a vector file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, software-recommendation, measurement, laser-cutting

I have a laser bed that people send me vector art to cut out. I charge by the inch and need a way to quickly select all of the vector artwork and get a total distance of all the paths.

Are there any software or plugins that can do that? I have Illustrator CC.

Comment: Hi Apetersen, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 7):

would this work for you? open Document Info Panel, select Objects. Right at the top you'll see the length of the selection.

[image]

Comment: I compaired the illustrator distance and multiplied it by the laser speed to get time ( distance X speed / 60 seconds) and compaired it to the actual run time of artwork. IT WAS THE SAME!!!! It's such an easy answer, thank you soooo much

Comment: @Apetersen: Make sure you are testing a mix of documents from simple to complex. Your test sample might be the *best case.*

Comment: I certainly did! The math transfers the real life application perfectly.